# roscore does not start

Tags: ros-noetic, roscore, debian, rosgraph

I am compiling Noetic from source under a Debian 12 bookworm distro for an arm64 SoC. After a successful build and install, if I launch the roscore command, I only see this in the console:

```
user@tigersd:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/0db85c88-c045-11ee-8667-ce581edff282/roslaunch-tigersd-1229.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
```

The process apparently gets stuck forever. If I hit Ctrl+C, I get the following traces:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/bin/roscore", line 84, in <module>
    roslaunch.main(['roscore', '--core'] + sys.argv[1:])
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 347, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 301, in start
    self.logger.info("starting roslaunch parent run")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 1489, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 1622, in _log
    fn, lno, func, sinfo = self.findCaller(stack_info, stacklevel)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py", line 67, in findCaller
    filename = os.path.normcase(co.co_filename)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen posixpath>", line 54, in normcase
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Looking at the involved Python code, in rosgraph/roslogging.py, class RospyLogger, function findCaller(), apparently the execution never leaves the following loop:

```
    while hasattr(f, "f_code"):
        # Search for the right frame using the data already found by parent class.
        co = f.f_code
        filename = os.path.normcase(co.co_filename)
        if filename == file_name and f.f_lineno == lineno and co.co_name == func_name:
            break
        if f.f_back:
            f = f.f_back
```

I added some print traces to see what are the values of the parameters checked in the *if* statement, and I really don't understand what is happening:

```
filename = /usr/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py, file_name = /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py, f.f_lineno = 1622, lineno = 58, co.co_name = _log, func_name = findCaller
filename = /usr/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py, file_name = /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py, f.f_lineno = 1489, lineno = 58, co.co_name = info, func_name = findCaller
filename = /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py, file_name = /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py, f.f_lineno = 301, lineno = 58, co.co_name = start, func_name = findCaller
filename = /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py, file_name = /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py, f.f_lineno = 347, lineno = 58, co.co_name = main, func_name = findCaller
filename = /opt/ros/noetic/bin/roscore, file_name = /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py, f.f_lineno = 84, lineno = 58, co.co_name = <module>, func_name = findCaller
filename = /opt/ros/noetic/bin/roscore, file_name = /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py, f.f_lineno = 84, lineno = 58, co.co_name = <module>, func_name = findCaller
filename = /opt/ros/noetic/bin/roscore, file_name = /opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosgraph/roslogging.py, f.f_lineno = 84, lineno = 58, co.co_name = <module>, func_name = findCaller
....
```

I have searched similar topics and I believe I have a regular working network in my system. ROS_IP is not set and ROS_MASTER_URI points to the usual localhost:11311. Ping finds my localhost and other host names as well. Any thoughts what could be happening here?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us how you define "forever"? What HW are you running?

Comment: I waited around 5 minutes and the master did not start. This process usually just takes a few seconds (3s-5s) in other platforms I have worked with. The HW is a Rockchip RK3588 SoC with 4GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit, however I don't really understand what is happening under the hood. I did not mention in my original post that I have Python 3.11 installed. I am guessing that the RospyLogger wrapper is not compatible with this version of Python.
What I did to fix my issue: go to rosgraph/roslogging.py, line 61 and modify to use the module's logging.currentframe() original function:

```
#f = inspect.currentframe()
f = logging.currentframe()
```

I found out that other people are experiencing the same issue:

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/2352

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/2353

Although my solution does not solve the issue completely, because the output log is now incomplete, I can at least continue porting my code to the new platform:

```
706880451.911240339 INFO /my_node [(unknown file):0((unknown function))] [topics: /rosout] Hello World INFO
```

If anyone knows the intrinsics of how the info is organized in the stack, I guess the issue could be solved the right way.

Thanks in advance!